# How to fix website bugs in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am fairly new here and to html and css.  I made this after struggling with the code:

- [www.shepherdstea.nl](http://www.shepherdstea.nl)

Now the question is that in Firefox, Chrome, etc the website works like I want it (given that in case you zoom in the middle sections moves - this needs to be fixed). But in Internet Explorer it just shows very weird. I hope you could help?

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific with your question and show some relevant code here, Frederik. Welcome to SO.

Comment: You should probably mention which IE versions you're targeting since there's much difference between them.

Comment: Which version of IE is the problem happening on? Which parts of your site are being displayed incorrectly? Post the code that you think is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you! It is the IE of Windows 8 (my first week with windows 8 so no clue where to find it).

Moreover the issue is that it shows the pictures with a blue border around it? 

How to post code here? just copy paste from editor?

Comment: Is *that* all? Just add `img{border:0}` to your CSS...

Comment: Niet the Dark, is that it? i was thinking super difficult things.. WHy does Chrome and the other browsers dont have this problem?

Comment: @Frederik Mastenbroek HTML1524: Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE. Consider using the interoperable form "<!DOCTYPE html>".
File: www.shepherdstea.nl, Line: 1, Column: 1....I am getting this error.Can you tell me how you fixed this error.

Answer (score 7):

Hit F12.

> HTML1524: Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE. Consider using the interoperable form "`<!DOCTYPE html>`".
>      File: www.shepherdstea.nl, Line: 1, Column: 1
>
> HTML1513: Extra "`<html>`" tag found. Only one "`<html>`" tag should exist per document.
>      File: www.shepherdstea.nl, Line: 10, Column: 1
>
> HTML1509: Unmatched end tag.
>      File: www.shepherdstea.nl, Line: 70, Column: 1
>
> HTML1512: Unmatched end tag.
>      File: www.shepherdstea.nl, Line: 98, Column: 104
>
> HTML1512: Unmatched end tag.
>      File: www.shepherdstea.nl, Line: 99, Column: 105
>
> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'offsetWidth' of undefined or null reference
>      File: jslider.js, Line: 94, Column: 7

Fix.

Comment: This is a surprisingly useful answer compared to the question asked. +1.

Comment: It just irritates me how many people blame Internet Explorer for following standards and rejecting their broken HTML...

Comment: This is not the problem of my website, as far as i know is html quite forgiven in makes made. The issue is that IE creates blue boxes around the the pictures. Why and how i dont understand, I just try to learn here

Comment: As I said in reply to your comment on the question, just add `img{border:0}` to your CSS.

Comment: done:) thank you very simple sollution. I am just new to html and all of this, so please forgive the incompetence here.